# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4294967295"

Tags: jdbc, rad

I google and know it is caused by retrieve a BLOB column using old ojdbc.jar.
But I already using ojdbc6.jar but still show this error.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4294967295"
```

I also try to add

```
System Property "oracledatabasemetadata.get_lob_precision" to false
```

as most google result told, but still show this error.

My project is using RAD and using attached WAS 7 bundle with RAD. how to know if System Property "oracledatabasemetadata.get_lob_precision" really set to false? I open the startServer.log and cannot find the keyword "-java -Doracledatabasemetadata.get_lob_precision"

How to fix the error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4294967295"
```

?

Answer (score 1):

solved it finally.
I wrongly set RAD WAS Custom Properties instead of Generic JVM arguments. after set

```
-Doracledatabasemetadata.get_lob_precision=false
```

in RAD WAS generic JVM argument (under Java and Process Management > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine), the error message does not show again.

Anyway, replace ojdbc14.jar to ojdbc6.jar does not solved the problem as recommended in others google result.